# Is the Prometheus Java Summary metric thread-safe?

Tags: java, spring, metrics, prometheus

Is the Prometheus Java `Summary` object thread-safe? If I declare it static in a class, it will be used by all instances of the class.  Does Prometheus implement thread-safety for this metric object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prometheus client libraries take care of details like thread safety for direction instrumentation such as the `Summary` class.